# UICollectionView Functionality issues

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewCell on VC1, The cell contains, a image, a label, and 3 buttons.

When i click on the cell. That triggers my `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` to take me to an Edit item screen.

**How can i access each button and relate it to the cell i am clicking on?**

So if i have added 6 cells, and i click on cell 1, button 1, it takes me to a bio page with info on that person. if i click on cell 2 button 1, it brings me to same bio VC but with different info related to the cell i clicked on.

**My confusion lies in where or how to set this up?**

Thank you!

```
    import UIKit
    import Parse


    class TrainersViewController: UIViewController,         UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, AddNewTrainerViewControllerDelegate {

var trainers: [TrainerArray]


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    trainers = [TrainerArray]()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    loadTrainerItems()
}

//connection to the collection view
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   print("selected")
   saveTrainerItems()

}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return trainers.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("TrainerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    var buttonOne = cell.viewWithTag(10)
    buttonOne = indexPath.row



    let trainer = trainers[indexPath.row]
    configureTrainerForCell(cell, withTrainerArray: trainer)
    return cell
}


func configureTrainerForCell(cell: UICollectionViewCell, withTrainerArray trainer: TrainerArray) {

    if trainer.trainerImage == nil {

        let label = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel
        trainer.trainerImage = UIImage(named: "defaultImage")
        label.text = trainer.name

    } else {
    let image = cell.viewWithTag(2000) as! UIImageView
    image.image = trainer.trainerImage

    let label = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel
    label.text = trainer.name
}
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   }


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//This method adds a new trainer to the trainer array
func addNewTrainerViewController(controller: AddNewTrainerViewController, didFinishAddingItem item: TrainerArray) {

    let newRowIndex = trainers.count
    trainers.append(item)

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: newRowIndex, inSection: 0)
    let indexPaths = [indexPath]
    collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    saveTrainerItems()

}

func addNewTrainerViewController(controller: AddNewTrainerViewController, didFinishDeletingItem item: TrainerArray) {

    if let index = trainers.indexOf(item) {

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
        let indexPaths = [indexPath]
        if let _ = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {

            self.trainers.removeAtIndex(index)
            self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)

        }
    }
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        saveTrainerItems()
}

//This Method Edits a Trainer
func addNewTrainerViewController(controller: AddNewTrainerViewController, didFinishEditingItem trainer: TrainerArray) {

    if let index = trainers.indexOf(trainer) {

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath){

            configureTrainerForCell(cell, withTrainerArray: trainer)
        }
    }
    saveTrainerItems()
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}


func addNewTrainerViewControllerDidCancel(controller: AddNewTrainerViewController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "AddTrainer" {

        let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! AddNewTrainerViewController
        controller.delegate = self

    } else if segue.identifier == "EditTrainer" {

        let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! AddNewTrainerViewController
        controller.delegate = self

        if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UICollectionViewCell) {

            controller.trainerToEdit = trainers[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}



func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
}

func documentsDirectory() -> String {

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    return paths[0]
}


func dataFilePath() -> String {

    return (documentsDirectory() as NSString)
                            .stringByAppendingPathComponent("Trainers.plist")
}

func saveTrainerItems() {

    let data = NSMutableData()
    let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWithMutableData: data)
    archiver.encodeObject(trainers, forKey: "TrainersArray")
    archiver.finishEncoding()
    data.writeToFile(dataFilePath(), atomically: true)
}

func loadTrainerItems() {

    let path = dataFilePath()
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path) {

        if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {

            let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: data)
            trainers = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey("TrainersArray") as! [TrainerArray]
            unarchiver.finishDecoding()
        }
    }
}


@IBAction func logOut(sender: AnyObject) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Are You Sure You Want To Log Out?", message: "Please Enter Your Username", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
        }

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Log Out", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        let textF = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField

        if textF.text! != PFUser.currentUser()?.username {
            self.displayGenericAlert("Incorrect Username!", message: "Please Enter a Valid Username")

        } else if textF.text! == PFUser.currentUser()?.username {
           PFUser.logOut()
           _ = PFUser.currentUser()
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        if action == true {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        }}))

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func displayGenericAlert(title: String, message: String) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    }))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func bioSegueButton(sender: AnyObject) {

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get data from your array from index 'indexpath.row' .

Comment: I got that, Should i now link a protocol and delegate between the two VC to be able to send info from TrainerCell to BioVC

Comment: If you are navigating through Segue then you can pass data in prepareForSegue method otherwise delegate is a option for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a tag to the button that corresponds to the index of the cell it is in. In the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you would add something like...

```
button.tag = indexPath.row
```

And in the selector for the button you can access it...

```
func buttonSelector(sender: UIButton) {
    let index = sender.tag
    let trainer = trainers[index]
}
```

EDIT:

A more complete version of what you might do in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("TrainerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? MyCollectionViewCell
    var buttonOne = cell?.button1
    buttonOne?.tag = indexPath.row

    let trainer = trainers[indexPath.row]
    configureTrainerForCell(cell, withTrainerArray: trainer)
    return cell!
}
```

Your collection view cell class:

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton! // connect this to the button in your interface builder's collection view cell.

    // Do the same for any other subviews.
}
```

Also in interface builder change the class of the collection view cell prototype to this new custom class.

Comment: I understand. I am going to give this a go now, Will report back shortly!

Comment: I cannot get it to work it seems. I have posted the code i have for `cellForItemAtIndexPath` above.

Comment: It looks like you're already using tags to grab the button you want. I'd recommend accessing the button directly using a property from your custom cell. Then you can assign a tag to that button. And when it's selector is called later, the tag will correspond to the indexPath.row, which will then let you access the correct data however that is kept. I'll try to edit to show this.

Comment: Ok, I only added the `let buttonOne = cell.viewWithTag(10)` after you told me to do `button.tag = indexPath.row` Now if i try to call `buttonOne = indexPath.row` i get error " cannot assign value of type `int` to value of type `UIView?`

Comment: i do not have a `class MyCollectionViewCell...` I am calling all of my methods for `collectionViewCell` in my main VC... i am new to swift. I have added the code for my VC, can you tell me what has to be moved into a `custom class` please.

Comment: i have a good feeling i am about to break what ever progress i have made so far.. :(

Comment: It will be ok! :) I'll edit to show more about using a custom collectionviewcell. Also, read carefully. You need to assign to buttonOne.tag, not just buttonOne.

Comment: OK! here is what i have so far? Tell me if this is progress or not? got in `cellForItemAt...` `let buttonOne = cell.viewWithTag(10)` also, `buttonOne?.tag = indexPath.row` Then in button method. i have.. `let index = sender.tag` also `let trainer = trainers[index]` finally, `print(trainer.name)` And it prints that corresponding rows name. So i guess that means it is connected? What is next to get custom info on the Vc?

Comment: Okay, now it is calling names, and segue'ing!  What should technically be my next step to display custom info on each cell? by the way prolfe Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: Do i have to set up delegation and protocols?

Comment: @MatthewEhrlich I'm not sure how you are wanting to display that trainer info. Sounds like it might be better if you created a new question for that. I do feel I should say that if you're using `let buttonOne = cell.viewWithTag(10)` then it's going to break as soon as you have to dequeue that cell and reuse it because you're changing the tag (it will no longer be the view with tag 10, your 11th cell would now only have that tag). Thus I'm suggesting using a custom class to get the reference to the button. Good luck

Comment: prolfe, I was able to get the reference to the button, when i click on the button it prints the name of the person i clicked on. Then i set up protocol and delegation to send the image through to the next view controller, Everything is set up and i get no errors, the only place it fails is it just doesn't display the image on the next VC can you check this out and see if you know why? Haven't gotten an answer. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097217/protocol-and-delegate-not-working-what-did-i-do-wrong?noredirect=1#comment55946665_34097217)