# Protocol and Delegate not working.. what did i do wrong?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uicollectionview, protocols

i am trying to send an image from my collectionViewCell imageView to an imageView in another VC through delegation and Protocol. I cannot figure out why this isn't working properly?

The sending VC is: `TrainersViewController`
The recieving VC is: `BioViewController`

Here is my protocol:

```
protocol TrainersViewControllerDelegate: class {

    func trainersViewController(controller: TrainersViewController, didFinishSendingImage trainer:TrainerArray)
}


class TrainersViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, AddNewTrainerViewControllerDelegate {

    weak var delegate: TrainersViewControllerDelegate? 
}
```

Here is my Receiving class:

```
class BioViewController: UIViewController, TrainersViewControllerDelegate {


    @IBAction func backToTrainersButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var bioImage: UIImageView!


    func trainersViewController(controller: TrainersViewController, didFinishSendingImage trainer: TrainerArray) {

        trainer.trainerImage! = bioImage as! UIImage
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "bioSegue" {
            let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! TrainersViewController
            controller.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Finally here is the button within the collectionViewCell that i am calling upon to make this happen:

```
    @IBAction func bioSegueButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let index = sender.tag
    let trainer = trainers[index]
    print(trainer.name)
    delegate?.trainersViewController(self, didFinishSendingImage: trainer)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("bioSegue", sender: self)
}
```

**Why is this not sending my image across into the imageView of the other VC?**

Comment: You're doing `trainer.trainerImage! = bioImage as! UIImage` which is going to crash because `bioImage` is not a `UIImage` its a `UIImageView`.  I'm pretty sure you want that to be `bioImage.image = trainer.trainerImage!`

Comment: Great! i switched that code around. It did not throw me any warnings or errors, meaning it works.. but when i click my button, to segue to Bio screen, it doesn't display any image.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with where i am calling the protocol function? i can't figure that part out..

Answer (score 0):

At the time when you call

```
delegate?.trainersViewController(self, didFinishSendingImage: trainer)
```

the variable `delegate` isn't set yet. You can check this with the following line:

```
print(delegate)
```

If the delegate isn't set, then this line will print `nil`

Comment: So how do i assure that the delegate is set and the picture is sent>

Comment: In which controller are you bioSegueButton action?

Comment: in the first controller, in my collectionViewCell

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass image in `prepareForSegue` and that would be simplest way (but you have to implement it in `sending` class). The previous answer is correct. You use it before you set delegate. If you really want to use it i would first perform the segue where when preparing for it you set the delegate and then try to use delegate method.

```
@IBAction func bioSegueButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let index = sender.tag
    let trainer = trainers[index]
    print(trainer.name)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("bioSegue", sender: self)
    delegate?.trainersViewController(self, didFinishSendingImage: trainer)
}
```

It could cause another problem but it would be not about delegation :)

You could try reversing your delegation. In `BioViewController` make `BioViewControllerDelegate` with method `bioViewControllerSetUpImage(bioViewController: BioViewController) -> UIImage` implement it in sending class and call it in BioViewController class for example in `viewDidLoad` like `bioImage = delegate?.bioViewControllerSetUpImage(self)`. Then you create `BioViewController`, set delegate, segue. (But this is my attempt to work it around, feel free to ignore it)